# how can i can the border-color of input field on error or invalid using angular js ??

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
     <input type="text" id="name" name="name"  placeholder="your name"  autocomplete="on" ng-model="name"  required>
```

now how to apply angular js here for validation ang changing input field border-color?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a code snippet you tried to use. It would help people answering your question greatly! Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I done the changes. Please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 angular.module('formExample', [])
   .controller('FormController', ['$scope',
     function($scope) {
       $scope.userType = 'guest';
     }
   ]);
```

```css
.my-form {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  background: transparent;
}
.my-form.ng-invalid {
  background: white;
}
.my-input.ng-invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="formExample">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
    userType:
    <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required class="my-input">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
    <br>
    <code>userType = {{userType}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</code>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Check this out.

```js
  angular.module('formExample', [])
    .controller('FormController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.userType = 'guest';
      }
    ]);
```

```css
.my-form {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
  background: transparent;
}
.my-form.ng-invalid {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="formExample">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
    userType:
    <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
    <br>
    <code>userType = {{userType}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</code>
    <br>
    <code>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</code>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
```

Source : [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

Comment: <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span>   u have shown a required message here .. but i want to change the border of  ng-model="userType"

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to add class to you element like:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"  placeholder="your name"  autocomplete="on" ng-model="name"  ng-class="{'has-error': (!formName.name.$pristine && formName.name.$error.required)}" required>
```

formName.name.$pristine : will check if any changes to name input element is been made.
formName.name.$error.required: will check error, here required is been checked.

in controller:

```
$scopr.submit = function () {
    if ($scope.formName.$valid) { 
      //do your work
    }
}
```

your need to create css class or If you are using twitter bootstrap use one from it.